# Mostrar Rut sin Guion MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando con mysql y tengo una tabla llamada alumno y uno de sus campos es Rut. El formato en el que guarda el Rut es Ej: 16777777-6, es decir sin puntos pero con guion. Lo que necesito es mostrar el rut en un campo pero que no me muestre el guion, solo los numeros Ej: 167777776.
Hasta ahora solo he encontrado formas de guardar el dato en mi base de datos con el formato que necesito, pero no tengo nada para mostrar el dato cuando ya lo tengo almacenado en mi BD.

Comment: ¿Y que has intentado?  ¿Que error te da?  ¿O solo quieres la solución? [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874)

Comment: Solo he encontrado formas de guardar el dato en la base de datos, pero no tengo nada para mostrar el dato como necesito.

Comment: ¿Pero lo has buscado?  ¿Y que has encontrado?  ¿nada?  ¿ni un triste ejemplo de [como reemplazar resultados de strings en una consulta SELECT en SQL](https://www.google.com/search?q=como+reemplazar+resultados+de+strings+en+una+consulta+select+en+SQL)? ¿O [como hacer una consulta SQL simple a MySQL](https://www.google.com/search?q=como+hacer+una+consulta+SQL+simple+a+MySQL)?

Comment: Gracias, la verdad no tengo tantos conocimientos y no sabia como hacerlo, pero me orientaste a lo que necesitaba, lo resolví con algo muy simple replace(rut,'-','').

Comment: Me alegro :-)  Google es tu amigo, solo tienes que preguntarle lo adecuado en cada caso y con las palabras adecuadas, que entiendo que quizas no sabias, pero empieza por lo simple y conforme vas aprendiendo el vocabulario sigues con el resto y seguro que lo sacas, como ya has visto ahora.